# Switching xeditable off and on using editable("destroy");

Tags: jquery, x-editable

I am trying to turn xeditable on and off using editable("destroy"). Xeditable turns off but does not turn back on. The function looks like this:

```
$("#changeType").on("change", function () {
    switch ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        case true:
            $("#status").editable("destroy");
            $("#status").editable({
                showbuttons: false,
                onblur: 'ignore',
                mode: 'inline',
                send: 'never',
                success: function (params) {
                    return false;
                }
            }).editable('show');
            break;
        case false:
            ("#status").editable("destroy");
            ("#status").editable();
            break;
    };
});
```

Please see my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ykay/vdoz07qz/3/

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. Please do not edit a question in a way that invalidates the answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a typo (missing `$` sign) in your `case false:`

```
$("#status").editable("destroy");
$("#status").editable();
```